# Create Combined Column From Three Columns With The Most Data (Not NA)

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,-2,3,0,0], [0,0,0,4,0], [0,0,0,0,5]]).T

df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    
> df

  col1 col2 col3
    1   0   0
    -2  0   0
    3   0   0
    0   4   0
    0   0   5
```

I want to create a fourth ("Col4") that takes the col that is non-zero.

So result would be:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
    1   0   0   1  
    -2  0   0   -2
    3   0   0   3
    0   4   0   4
    0   0   5   5
```

EDIT: If two non-zero, always use `col1`. Also, the numbers may be negative. I have updated the `df` to reflect this.

Comment: Which value should be taken if there are different non zero values in the columns? Why does `col1` change in your expected output?

Comment: thanks, that was a typo, fixed now. Col1 should always be provided (it should be the 'default')

Comment: If you have more requirements ('Col1 should always be provided') please edit your question. For your example `df['col4'] = df.max(1)` works, but could be a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the maximum of the columns is a possibility

```
df['col4'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: thats a great and clever solution. However, it won't work for negative numbers. I added this to the question, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Replacing 0 with nan could work in that case. However, column 1 is not the default.
    
`df['col4'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
def func(a):
  a = set(a)
  assert len(a)==2  # 0 and another number
  for i in a:
    if i!=0:
      return i
df['col4'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```